# Add VM Instance to an Instance Group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm brand new to GCP and I'm trying to get an instance up and running. I'm noticing that the instance seems to be not healthy because the IP is not connecting. I want to check the health of the instance but I think it needs to belong to an instance group before I can do that. But I can't see how to add an instance to a group.

Here is the UI:

[image]

I want to add the `statcasters-instance` to the `statcasters-group` instance group. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the instance "not being healthy"?  What specific recipe are you using to create a compute engine instance?  What might you be seeing/not-seeing vs expecting to see?  Instance groups are all about load balancers and availability but I get the impression the puzzle is distinct from that.

Comment: I've arrived here in a moment of desperation while trying to initialise a new VM inside an existing Instance Group. Weirdly enough, this is done via editing the Instance Group and changing the `Number of instances` field to `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) documentation. There are 2 kinds of VM instance groups.

- Managed instance groups
- Unmanaged instance groups

**Managed instance groups** are groups that can be created using an Instance Template. You can't add a new instance to that group as this is a managed by Google. You can only create a new Instance Template and then create a new Instance Group from that template.

**Unmanaged instance groups** are group that are managed by your self. However, when creating an `Unmanaged instance group` you specify the `Network` for this instance group. You can add VM instnaces to that group later, as long as those VM instances are part of that network as well. To do so, go to the `Instance groups` page in Google Cloud Console, and click on your unmanged instance group's name. This will open the instance group details page. Click on `EDIT GROUP`. In the `VM Instances` choose the VM instance that is not already in the group and add it to the group.

Comment: one thing to note, with regards to unmanaged instance group, make sure your vm instances under the same availability zone as your unmanaged instance group.

Example: VM instances in us-central1 with zone us-central1-a  can't be added to Unmanaged instance group us-central1-c

Answer (score 0):

If it's an "unmanaged" instance group you can add an existing VM instance to the group with

```
gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged add-instances $INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME \
    --zone=$ZONE \
    --instances=$INSTANCE_NAME
```